# How to force QTcpServer listen on a specific port?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Is it possible to force QTcpServer to listen to a specific port smaller than 1024?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are on Linux? If so, This restriction comes from OS, not from QTcpServer. Try using sudo.